# How fill an object correctly using [key: type]: value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the data filtered from an array of objects using the column's name from a table.

The columns are dynamic, the columns could be hidden or showing any moment any time, so the values I get directly from the table.

```
['referenceName', 'shipmentId', 'freightType', 
'etd', 'eta', 'notes', 'company', 'origin', 'carrier',
 'voyageNumber', 'actualDeparture']
```

This is one of the JSON

[image: json]

#### My code

```
console.log('elements', this.elements[0]);
    const currentsColumns = Object.keys(this.columnOptions);
    const dataTableFiltered = [];
    const elementsTable: {[key: string]: any} = {}

    this.elements.forEach((element, index: number) => {
      Object.keys(element).map((key) => {
        const elementKey = key;
        if (currentsColumns.includes(elementKey)){
          if((typeof element[key]) === 'object'){
            elementsTable['key'] = (JSON.stringify(element[elementKey]));
          }else{
            elementsTable['key'] = element[elementKey]
          }
        }
      });
    })
```

The result is all data repeated the number of the original array of json.

[image: result]

Comment: I think `elementsTable['key']` should be `elementsTable[key]`

Comment: Let me try with your code

Comment: @GrafiCode Don't work, still saving the last object.

Comment: uhm `elementsTable` should be an array. it's an object instead, and it gets overwritten on every element iteration. I'm not sure how that should be declared in typescript, this is how I would do it in javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/ek4wj3pt/2/

Comment: That's work in the example, let me try.

Comment: @GrafiCode Return all undefined